# Mocking sqlalchemy.create_engine fails to mock the function

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I want to test my DBConnect class, which manages and returns connections made with sqlalchemy.

I want to specifically test that the constructor of DBConnect calls `sqlalchemy.create_engine` and stores the engine in the `connection`.

My test function is this:

```py
from unittest import mock
from catcom.db_connect import DBConnect
import os

class MockEngine:
    def connect(self):
        return "test_connection"

@mock.patch("sqlalchemy.create_engine", return_value=MockEngine())
def test_from_key_uses_correct_key(mock):
    print(mock)
    db = DBConnect("user", "pw", "127.0.0.1", "1234", "db")
    assert db.connection == "test_connection"
```

However, I see a response of:

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 1234 failed: Connection refused
E               Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

How can I mock the `create_engine` method without it being actually called?

**UPDATE**

Adding the DB Connect class and relevant methods.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

class DBConnect:
    """Manages database connection using SQLalchemy"""

    def __init__(self, user: str, password: str, host: str, port: str, database: str):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.database = database
        self.connection = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        """creates a connection object that is used to query database using SQLalchemy core
        automatically created in __init__"""
        engine = create_engine(
            f"postgresql+psycopg2://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.database}"
        )
        return engine.connect()
```

Comment: What's in your `DBConnect` class ? Are you using `import sqlalchemy` or `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` ?

Comment: I added exerpts from that class relevant here. I've tried to use imports in any configuration I can think of so far. but currently there is no import of sqlalchemy on the test and `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `create_engine` out of the `sqlalchemy` namespace with `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`, which puts it in the module's namespace.

That's what you need to patch, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

```py
@mock.patch('catcom.db_connect.create_engine', return_value='test_success')
```

Although, patching `catcom.db_connect.create_engine` to return `'test_success'` will cause a problem when the `DBConnect.connect` method tries to call the `connect` method of the engine (which will be a string).

Comment: Thanks, I got the namespace wrong. I've updated the return value bit in the request as it's a perfectly valid observation but did not cause the real issue.